# Lingot not detecting sound from microphone

Tags: 10.10, sound, music

I installed lingot(guitar tuner- http://freshmeat.net/projects/lingot/) on Ubuntu but it doesn't seem to be detecting the sounds from the microphone. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Lingot's default sound input device is set to a raw Alsa input (e.g. `plughw:0`). In the Ubuntu desktop these inputs are opened in exclusive mode by PulseAudio, preventing other applications from opening them.

The solution is to make Lingot use the sound input device provided by PulseAudio, which is called `pulse`.

Either edit Lingot's configuration file `$HOME/.lingot/lingot.conf` and set

```
AUDIO_SYSTEM = ALSA
AUDIO_DEV_ALSA = pulse
```

or open Lingot's preferences window and set *Audio System* to **ALSA** and *Audio Device* to **pulse**.

Answer (score 2):

### Update 2019

On another system I needed to set Audio device to `plughw:1,0` as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/364729/315347).

### Previous answer

Thanks @zwets your answer is the correct one. I'm just posting a screenshot of the preferences menu, in case it helps someone. Lingot's configuration is set as follows:

- Audio system set to Alsa
- Audio device set to pulse

[image]

You can see in the main Lingot window that my guitar is playing the E string.