# Lingot is not working.

Tags: 12.04, sound, headphones, logitech, lingot

I am using Ubuntu 12.04...
I wan to tune my acoustic guitar using Lingot....
But it gives just no response to any sound... I tried changing the

`AUDIO_DEV = /dev/dsp`

to

`AUDIO_DEV = /dev/audio`

as read on a forume but no luck....
I have Logitech headphones..

Please, also tell me if I can redirect the system's sound *output* to Lingot's sound *input* so that I can identify the notes of song that is being played (say in VLC player)...

My current audio settings of Lingot:

`Audio settings: ALSA`

`Audio device: plughw:0`

Answer (score 2):

Change 
`plughw:0` 
and put 
`plughw:1,0`
I think you just need to do that.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?